# SQL, T-SQL. In TRIGGER I want to duplicate an entire line (consisting of 50 columns). I have to write by hand INSERT with all the columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

I'm using a trigger to check if the last row inserted in a table contains some specifically value, for example the column PLAYER_TYPE = 'P01' (it's an example).

Now I want a trigger that duplicate the new row (consisting of 50 columns), so the last row inserted in table (so the trigger is on "after") by changing just some column values.

So, for example, if the row is like this:

```
INSERT INTO Players_Table (ID, NAME, GAMES, OPPONENT... and so on by 50 columns!!!)
VALUES (one, two, three, four... and so on by 50 columns!!!)
```

How to change just some values and copy the entire row without write by hand each column?

Comment: Don't be lazy, specifying each column makes your application more robust for table changes.

Comment: Information_schema.column plus Dynamic sql

Comment: @NoDisplayName, can you be more explicit?

Comment: @JohnSam Are you wanting to duplicate (copy) the new row with different values for some columns or are you wanting to update the values of some of the columns on the newly inserted row?

Comment: @ChristianBarron: The first.

Answer (score 0):

I think I mis-read this originally.

If you want to update the last inserted row then you can do this in your trigger:

```
Update Players_Table
Set ColumnA = newValue,
ColumnB = newValue
Where ID = (Select ID from Inserted)
and Player_Type = 'P01'
```

Otherwise you could perform an insert of the duplicate first and then perform the update afterwards. This is a lazy way and you will sacrifice performance for laziness. It would be better to do the following:

```
Declare @changedValue1 varchar(100),
@changedValue2 varchar(100)
Set @changedValue1 = 'new value'
Set @changedValue2 = 'new value'
Insert Into Players_Table
Select column1, column2, column3, @changedValue1, column5, @changedValue2, column6 etc
from Inserted
```

Comment: not recommended. if, in future, we add or remove columns then it will create problem.

Comment: Yes it is definitely not recommended but this is a solution to his query

Comment: Dear @ChristianBarron, I want to modify some values in that "all values" without specify all columns in INSERT INTO. How to?

Comment: This will also break if/when `inserted` contains multiple rows.

Comment: You mis-read again. I need to save the row. Than I want to copy the last row, duplicate and save this row with some values different from the inserted row. Row A saved > duplicate row A > change some values > save the new row (B) with some values changed. How to?

Comment: @JohnSam Like I say, if you don't want to specify each column you'd have to Perform another insert e.g. Insert Into Players_Table Select * from Inserted and then perform the update statement after that. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to save having to type the column names and you are using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) then try this;

1. find the table in the object browser,
2. expand the table node,
3. drag the word 'Columns' into your query

This will give you all the column names.

Rhys

Comment: Thanks, but I need code. Not just this time. I'm using a trigger.